# query to find monday in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have table that show order detail,
i want to find product that only ordered in monday.

i can't find query to execute it,
because

```
where dayofweek(orderDate)=2;
```

it doesnt work in bigquery

[screenshot my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqW9i.png)

query to filter date only Monday

Comment: If you search the BigQuery documentation for DAYOFWEEK you will find the answer